# How to rearange digits abcde to different digits order in TASM 8086? Constant too long

Tags: assembly, tasm

For example I have user input of abcde (5 digits, each letter represents different digit). And I want to rearrange digits order, from abcde to acda (12345 becomes 1341)
So, I extract each digit and multiply by its position. Code below gives me extracted cda:

```
 ; XXXO
 mov al, 1 ; al becomes 1
 mov bl, byte ptr[input + 2] ; a
 sub bl, '0' ; converts from ASCII to number
 mul bl ; al = 1 and multiplied by digit a, so answer is a*1
 mov byte ptr firstNumber, al

 ;XXOX
 mov al, 10
 mov bl, byte ptr[input+ 5] ; d
 sub bl, '0'
 mul bl ; d * 10
 mov byte ptr secondNumber, al

 ; XOXX
 mov al, 100
 mov bl, byte ptr[input+ 4] ; c
 sub bl, '0'
 mul bl ; c * 100
 mov word ptr thirdNumber, ax
```

because a*1+d*10+c*100. Summation shown below:

```
 mov cl, 00
 add cl, byte ptr numberOne
 add cl, byte ptr numberTwo
 add cx, word ptr numberThree
```

Now the problem is extracing the a*1000 digit, because

```
 ; OXXX
 mov al, 1000 ; Error here. Constant too large
 mov bl, byte ptr[input+ 2] ; a
 sub bl, '0'
 mul bl
 mov word ptr fourthNumber, ax
```

gives constant too large error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`al` is a 8 bit register, it can hold values up to 256 only. You will need to use a 16 bit register, eg. `ax` and extend the other operand too, such as:

```
mov ax, 1000
movzx bx, byte ptr [input+2]
sub bx, '0'
mul bx
mov word ptr thirdNumber, ax
```

If you want to avoid `movzx`, you can zero `bh` by hand:

```
mov ax, 1000
mov bl, byte ptr [input+2]
sub bl, '0'
mov bh, 0
mul bx
mov word ptr thirdNumber, ax
```

Comment: movzx bx, byte ptr [input + 5] ;  Illegal instruction for currently selected processor(s)

Comment: Select a non-ancient processor? Or use the workaround (see update).